# Apple headphones maximum db output?

Tags: macbook-pro, ear-phones

I've recently got hooked to listening to white noise at work because it helps me focus amidst all the noise. I use the brown noise generator from [SimplyNoise](http://www.simplynoise.com) for this. I was trying to measure if it was safe to actually listen to noise for around 6-7 hours a day.

For evaluating this, pretty much the only references I've found was that listening to noise at 64dB for 6-7 hours a day is considered "safe" which lead me down this road.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extracted form [Apple's Store](http://store.apple.com/us_smb_78313/product/MA850G/B/apple-in-ear-headphones-with-remote-and-mic) In-Ear Headphone's overview:

> **Technical Specifications**
>
> - Frequency response: 5Hz to 21kHz
> - Impedance (at 100Hz): 23 ohms
> - Sensitivity (at 100Hz): **109 dB SPL/mW**
> - Drivers: Custom two-way balanced armature (woofer and tweeter in each earpiece)

If you are using the regular Earphones, although I couldn't find any official technical specs, it's dB output would be lower than the In-Ear's, something like **103 dB.**

And for the *safe* decibels, just remember that:

> - A typical conversation occurs at 60 dB – not loud enough to cause    damage.
> - A bulldozer that is idling (note that this is idling, not    actively bulldozing) is loud enough at 85 dB that it can cause permanent damage after only 1 work day (8 hours).
> - When listening to a personal music system with stock earphones at    a maximum volume, the sound generated can reach a level of over    100
>     dBA, loud enough to begin causing permanent damage after just    15
>     minutes per day!
> - A clap of thunder from a nearby storm (120 dB) or a gunshot (140-190    dB,    depending on weapon), can both cause immediate
>     damage.

Comment: Thanks! I listen at about 30% of the max volume. Should be ok?

Comment: Well, if it's roughly 100 dB at maximum volume, you could safely reach to 50%. 30% is perfect, though, if thats enough for you.

Comment: Good info on the decibel levels!